# prevent onChanged on back button pressed textfield

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a text field in which inside onChanged i'm calling an API everything is working fine, but when i press the back button(to hide keyboard) onChanged function is called again, How can i prevent this?
This is the code for my textfield.

```
TextField(
  onChanged: (text) {
    searchProvider.makeSearchQuery(text);
  },
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
        Radius.circular(10),
      ),
    ),
    labelText: "Enter Term to search.",
  ),
);
```

Comment: Could you please share a minimal code?

Comment: @Prince i have added the code.